# How do I connect this anemometer to a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: pi-3, gpio, sensor, connection, wiring

I want to connect an anemometer to my Raspberry Pi 3.
I'm trying to use the [Maplin N25FR Wind Speed Sensor](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Wind-Speed-Sensor-For-Use-With-Wireless-Weather-Station-N25FR/201474546389?epid=1008892760&hash=item2ee8d19ad5:g:T1kAAOSwt6ZWWLVS).

How do I connect it to my Raspberry Pi?

I found this picture online, but I don't understand how it's connected and what device is being used to connect it.
[image]

Comment: You may be better off searching for Raspberry Pi plus the sensor you are interested in.  Such hits are likely to find a sensor and how to interface that model of sensor to the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but i would prefer using the maplin anemometer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the item you have circled is a GPIO extender which just makes connection to the GPIO pins on the Raspberry Pi a lot simpler. There are lots of different types available and it is even possible that the one in the image is home-made.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Could you please suggest a GPIO extender similar to the one he's using that i might be able to use. FYI the wire of the sensor is a RJ11.

Comment: I'm not aware of any thing on the market that will accept RJ11 and connect direct to GPIO. It looks as if someone else is doing a similar project at https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=116308 

You may find something of help there.